# Symmetric Bandstop Filter in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, filter

I'm using Matlab to find effective ways of deconvolving the output of a spectrometer to get the original input. The function deconvwnr() works well, except it introduces a lot of sinusoidal-esque noise which I have been getting rid of with matlab's built-in band-stop butterworth filtering:

```
[b,a] = butter(3,[iters-freq,iters+freq],'stop'); recovered = filter(b,a,toBS);
```

The problem is that this filter is one-sided, defined as

If x[n] is the array and y[n] is the filtered array, f:x->y is one-sided iff y[n] = f( x[n], x[n-1], x[n-2]...)

and introduces a shift in the spectrometer peaks:

[image: shift]

Thus, I need to use a two-sided, symmetric filter. Is there an easy, built-in way to do this in Matlab?

---Alternatively---are there any really good, "it just works", noise-tolerant deconvo algorithms out there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All filters produce a "shift" or "delay" in the output by as many number of samples as the length of the filter. This is the behaviour using the `filter` command.

To get no delay in the output, you should filter it once forward and once backward (+shift -shift =0). This is easily implemented using the [`filtfilt`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/signal/filtfilt.html) command. The syntax is

```
filtfilt(b,a,toBS)
```

The drawback (if you really care about this) is that the effective filter order is doubled.